# Can't upload image from RPI 3 to Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, google-play-services, firebase-storage, android-things

I'm trying to upload an image from *Raspberry Pi 3* to *Firebase Storage* but can't do it. I tried different versions of __Firebase_ libraries (11.4.2, 11.6.0, 11.8.0), but I always got the same result.
I use **OS Build OIM1.171126.016**

*Firebase* dependecies from `build.gradle`:

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.6.0"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.0"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.0"
```

Code for upload image:

```
private void onPictureTaken(final byte[] imageBytes) {
        if (imageBytes != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Picture taken");
            StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
            StorageReference feederRef = storageRef.child("test/test.jpg");

            feederRef.putBytes(imageBytes).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                    Log.e(TAG, exception.getMessage(), exception);
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    Log.d(TAG, "downaload uri = " + downloadUrl);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Log:

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services is missing.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0
E/NetworkRqFactoryProxy: NetworkRequestFactoryProxy failed with a RemoteException:
                         com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zzc: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
                             at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source:176)
                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzewy.<init>(Unknown Source:18)
                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzewy.zzh(Unknown Source:13)
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzcjq(Unknown Source:8)
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source:105)
                             at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source:2)
                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/UploadTask: Unable to create a network request from metadata
              android.os.RemoteException
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzewy.<init>(Unknown Source:85)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzewy.zzh(Unknown Source:13)
                  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzcjq(Unknown Source:8)
                  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source:105)
                  at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source:2)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/StorageException: null
                    android.os.RemoteException
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzewy.<init>(Unknown Source:85)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzewy.zzh(Unknown Source:13)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzcjq(Unknown Source:8)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source:105)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source:2)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/StorageException: null
                    android.os.RemoteException
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzewy.<init>(Unknown Source:85)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzewy.zzh(Unknown Source:13)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzcjq(Unknown Source:8)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source:105)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source:2)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/StorageException: null
                    android.os.RemoteException
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzewy.<init>(Unknown Source:85)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzewy.zzh(Unknown Source:13)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzcjq(Unknown Source:8)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source:105)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run(Unknown Source:2)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Rule in *Firebase Storage*:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/my-app.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `Google Play services is missing`. Probably that's the reason. Install them.

Comment: When I created build for rpi I set true for "Include these Google services". How else can I install Google Play services?

Comment: Check if the services are really presented in the system with `adb shell pm list packages`. Check the output for `com.google.android.gms`

Comment: @Onik I didn't found package in the list. Do you know how can I install `com.google.android.gms` in Android Things

Comment: In that case try to get a new Bundle from console and reflash the new image.

Comment: @Onik with new bundle is everything ok, thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the *logcat* messages:

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services is missing.
```

Check if package `com.google.android.gms` is installed in the system with

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

In case the package is missing try getting a new *Android Things* Bundle from the console and reflashing the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Google Play Services classPath dependency to your root build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

And things module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

More info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: This allows you to make use of `Google Play services` within your app. But what are you going to do if there is no `Google Play services` running on a device?

Comment: Good point, his gradle file didn't have the gms, so it was a first guess